# Assign iterative number to n rows from variable

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
ndf = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(6)})
print(ndf)
```

Current input:

```
   col1
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
```

How to use a variable (myVar = 4) to enumerate every 'myVar rows' and assign 1, then repeat then ext 'myVar rows' and increment to 2, and so on.

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: Are you saying rows can only be assigned 1 or 2?

Comment: No, this is an example. If I had 22 (so not always equally grouped) [or 100] rows the first 4 rows would be assigned '1', the next 4 rows would be assigned '2', and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like you can solve this with a little integer division:

```
df['subgroup'] = df.index // myVar + 1
df
    col1  subgroup
0      0         1
1      1         1
2      2         1
3      3         1
4      4         2
5      5         2
```